# Recommendation for references on the philosophy of space and time

Tags: reference-request, time, space

I am a mathematician by training but I have absolutely no formal (or even informal) training in philosophy. I am also beginning a project to write short stories with a heavy focus on mathematics, in particular about the geometry of space-time and general relativity. But I would like to familiarize myself with related topics in philosophy to enrichen my writing. As such, I am looking for recommendations on good references, preferably at the introductory level or at least digestible for someone with sufficient math and physics knowledge, on the philosophy of space and time.

A cursory browsing brought me to the Wikipedia page on the [philosophy of space and time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_space_and_time) and the references section inside provides many options. But I feel a bit intimidated by the size of this list and, as I have no experience in philosophy, I do not know what is a good place to start.

I am hoping for some guidance on which reference to begin with, whether it be one in the above list or anything else you prefer to recommend. (Perhaps I really require prior knowledge of the basics of the field before diving into this topic, in which case I'm sure there is a standard guide for a philosophy-quick-start you can direct me to. I might really not know what I'm getting myself into here with this project.) Thanks!

Comment: I don't know a lot about contemporary philosophy of physics, but, if you're curious about Kant's views and their influence, I would highly reccomend reading David J. Hyder's papers on Kant on time and his book *The Determinate World*. Also, Thomas Ryckman's *The Reign of Relativity* is a great resource on interactions between philosophy and physics (especially neo-Kantianism, phenomenology and Weyl). Michael Friedman wrote some interesting pieces about conventionalism and logical positivism (Reichenbach, Schlick, Grunbaum etc.). But I don't reccomend his works on Kant.

Comment: I think this will provide enough historical background to understand the later developments.

Comment: @abracadabra Thank you, I will look into these. Hopefully they're at a level I'm comfortable with.